# Get IP address of website

Tags: domains, ip-address, godaddy

How do I access my website using the IP address? I tried to ping my site `example.com` and it gives the IP address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, but when I try to browse my website using the IP address its responded with "pageok". My hosting is GoDaddy and it's a shared host.

I tried to check how many websites are hosted on that IP using [yougetsignal.com](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/) and this is the result:

> Found 855 domains hosted on the same web server as `example.com` (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).

Do you think there is a way to browse my site using only the IP address?

Comment: No. It is impossible. In fact, these servers have catch-all sites just for this purpose- to capture IP only accesses. You will not be able to have IP only access to your site without a dedicated server and dedicated IP address.

Comment: When navigating to ip address which is exactly what your domain name is pointing on, browser sends different HTTP "Host" header, this way server can host multiple websites on one IP address. This is a good explanation: [How do you have one IP address and many websites? - serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/106909)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have a dedicated IP address you cannot pull up your website using one. Shared hosts will put hundreds or thousands of sites on a single IP address. And as you can see the IP address itself will default to some page that is the default one for that server.

Comment: Great minds think alike...

Comment: So do sick ones....

Comment: I almost added ...and madmen in asylums.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. A dedicated IP is required to identify a website as in Shared host it is impossible. If you opt for that, you have to bear some extra hosting cost, but a dedicated IP can help you to access the website better.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to browse your site using IP address. You just need to purchase dedicated IP from your hosting provider, then you will be able to browse your site using IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Your website hosted on shared hosting, You have to buy a dedicated IP address from your shared hosting provider. Which is just assign only for your hosting account. then you access your website with your Dedicated IP address. and it cost you some extra price per month.